# How to get the information / different variable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

**Updated 2015-04-12**

I have a problem in PHP that I don't know how to correctly to use information. Here is the code:

```
            $info = array();
            $plus = 0;
            $item = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE vardas='$ID' AND uzdetas='1' ORDER BY id");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($item)) {
              $info[$plus] = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM daiktai WHERE id='".$row['daiktas']."'"));
              $plus = $plus + 1;
            }

            $empty = "block.png";

            if ($info[0]['tipass'] == 1) {
                $helm = "".$info[0]['img']."";
            } else {
                $helm = "helm.png";
            }
            if ($info[1]['tipass'] == 9) {
                $amulet = "".$info[1]['img']."";
            } else {
                $amulet = "amulet.png";
            }
            if ($info[2]['tipass'] == 8) {
                $sword = "".$info[2]['img']."";
            } else {
                $sword = "sword.png";
            }
            if ($info[3]['tipass'] == 3) {
                $platebody = "".$info[3]['img']."";
            } else {
                $platebody = "platebody.png";
            }
            if ($info[4]['tipass'] == 3) {
                $shield = "".$info[4]['img']."";
            } else {
                $shield = "shield.png";
            }
            if ($info[5]['tipass'] == 7) {
                $platelegs = "".$info[5]['img']."";
            } else {
                $platelegs = "platelegs.png";
            }
            if ($info[6]['tipass'] == 6) {
                $gloves = "".$info[6]['img']."";
            } else {
                $gloves = "gloves.png";
            }
            if ($info[7]['tipass'] == 7) {
                $boots = "".$info[7]['img']."";
            } else {
                $boots = "boots.png";
            }
            if ($info[8]['tipass'] == 1) {
                $ring = "".$info[8]['img']."";
            } else {
                $ring = "ring.png";
            }

            echo "<div class='equipment'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$helm."'  alt='' width='30' class='head'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$empty."'  alt='' width='30' class='cape'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$amulet."'  alt='' width='30' class='amulet'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$empty."'  alt='' width='30' class='arrows'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$sword."'  alt='' width='30' class='sword'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$platebody."'  alt='' width='30' class='platebody'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$shield."'  alt='' width='30' class='shield'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$platelegs."'  alt='' width='30' class='platelegs'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$gloves."'  alt='' width='30' class='gloves'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$boots."'  alt='' width='30' class='boots'>
                <img src='img/daiktai/".$ring."'  alt='' width='30' class='ring'>
            </div>";
```

I posted all code!

**What I want?** In MySQL are items with different information and all players can get them (items). I want to do that if human have item with type 1, so the variable will be:

```
            if ($info[0]['tipass'] == 1) {
                    $helm = "".$info[0]['img']."";
            } else {
                    $helm = "helm.png";
            }
```

And if the type is 2, so the variable must to be also:

```
            if ($info[1]['tipass'] == 9) {
                    $amulet = "".$info[1]['img']."";
            } else {
                    $amulet = "amulet.png";
            }
```

As a result, I want to show them:

```
<img src='img/daiktai/".$helm."'  alt='' width='30' class='head'>
<img src='img/daiktai/".$amulet."'  alt='' width='30' class='amulet'>
..
```

and etc. The problem is that the code correctly shows just helm and amulet, but human wears also sword, boots and etc. Please correct my code, thank you!

Comment: [This `"".$information['item_image].""` should be throwing you an error.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: I don't think, because I'm getting the 1st of image type informaton. Maybe you have a suggestion how to correct it?

Comment: Stack's syntax highlighting doesn't lie. Plus, I know it will throw/cause a parse error.

Comment: So, maybe you know the desicion to my question?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I've removed the [solved] tag, we don't do that here. I think your second question deserves its own question, since this one has been both answered and closed as unclear. FWIW I don't understand the second question anyway, so would you ask that as a separate question, remove it from here by editing, and in your new question expand on detail greatly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your `$information` variable every time the loops runs.  You need to set `$information` as an array and push values into it at different indices.

```
$information = array();
$index = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $information[$index] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE   id='".$row['item_name']."'"));
     // Increment our index every time the loop runs
     $index = $index + 1;
}
```

You can generate a list of HTML images from this array using a loop

```
for($information as $image){
    echo "<img src=$image['item_image']";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but how to display now the information? Because `$information['name']` doesn't work.

Comment: @Programmer You're not listing the index when you use `$information['name']`.  You need to call `$information[0]['name']` instead.  A cleaner way to display every image associated with an index in the array is to run a loop.  See the edited answer above.

Comment: Oh. It's really array..Forgot.. Lack of knowledge.. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Updated the question, please help. :)

Comment: @Programmer You need to use a loop so that all the indice values are displayed

Comment: I'm getting error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in..` Also I'm using while loop and writed for loop below.

Comment: @Programmer Can you post the code you're running in your question?

Comment: I posted new code with new variables. Check this out! Thanks.

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer. Please help me.

Comment: Please man.. I'm waiting for your answer.. The question was updated.

Comment: Updated the question more better! 2015-04-12. Please help.